# Select query on a Table based on condition from other table ? No Foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to make a select query from table A if a different select query returns from table B.
Query in table can be select 1 from B where x= something.
Query in Table A can be entirely different.

Can i do this in a single SQL query ?
What is the best way to achieve this ?

I am using postgres

Comment: You are going to have to be a lot more specific with what you are asking for anybody to be able to answer this properly, that said, case conditionals are possible in sql queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sounds of it you want something like:

```
SELECT  A.SomeColumn, A.AnotherColumn
FROM    A
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.X = Something);
```

Comment: How do i differentiate between the cases when Table A is empty and condition passed , other case being when the condition failed . In Both the cases query will return null

Comment: You can't really without a separate query. In the same way if you ran a query `select a from t where a = 1` and no results are returned you wouldn't know if t was empty or there were no rows where a was 1 unless you ran `select count(a) from t`